# Incrementing the for loop in python given a certain condition

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

The `i+=1` isn't working, it should have increased the `i` value but it isn't.

```
n = int(input())

for j in range(n):
    a = input()
    pair = 0
    
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        print(i)
        if a[i] == "x" and a[i+1] == "y":
            pair += 1
            print("*")
        elif a[i] == "y" and a[i+1] =="x":
            pair += 1
            print('**')
        else:
            continue
        i+=1
        print(pair)
        print("****")
    print(pair)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for-loop` already increments `i` on every iteration. But if you want to increment by more than 1 when certain condition is satisfied, then you can use `while` loop as follows:

```py
n = int(input())

for j in range(n):
    a = input()
    pair = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(a)-1:
        print(i)
        if a[i] == "x" and a[i+1] == "y":
            pair += 1
            print("*")
        elif a[i] == "y" and a[i+1] =="x":
            pair += 1
            print('**')
        else:
            i += 1
            continue
        i+=2
        print(pair)
        print("****")

    print(pair)strong text
```

Comment: This requires having a `i += 1` on every continue, which is very error prone imo. I'd suggest wrapping the `i += 1` with a `try: finally`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really see how it could go wrong. `continue` just says move on to the next iteration, which starts with checking if `i < len(a) - 1`. This upper bound makes sure that `i` and `i+1` are valid indices of `a`,

Comment: Of course your code is correct, but somebody when editing it later will forget the i += 1 in some special case. With robust i mean robust in future editing.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify a parameter that is implicitly set by the for loop.
This isn't C-Code, increasing the counter variable will **not** skip the next iteration.

The reason for that is quite simple: `for` itself does *not* increase `i` in every iteration, it just steps through the given iteratable. In this case the iteratable is a range, which behaves like `for` would increase `i` every iteration, but it really just takes the next value from the range.

So `i+=1` doesn't have an effect on the next iteration, as it doesn't modify the next value in the `range`.

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitely skip the next iteration when a pair is found.

Here is your code with the changes pointed at by `# <---`.

```
n = int(input())

for j in range(n):

    a = input()
    pair = 0
    skip_next = False # <---
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if skip_next is True: # <---
            skip_next = False # <---
            continue          # <---
        print(i)
        if a[i] == "x" and a[i+1] == "y":
            pair += 1
            print("*")
            skip_next = True # <---
        elif a[i] == "y" and a[i+1] =="x":
            pair += 1
            print('**')
            skip_next = True # <---
        else:
            continue
        print(pair)
        print("****")
    print(pair)
```